# How to add a dev dependency with angular schematics extending from ng-new

Tags: angular, typescript, dependencies, angular-schematics

I need to add dev dependencies when i use ng-new external schematic

I tried many things but right now the most successful one is the this:

```
    context.addTask(
      new NodePackageInstallTask({
        workingDirectory: `./${options.name}`,
        packageName: "lodash-es",
      })
    );
```

This adds a dependency the problem is i cannot specify or i dont now how to specify that this dependency is a dev dependency. The other way i tried is using this in my schematic

```
    [
      {
        type: NodeDependencyType.Dev,
        name: "husky",
        version: "*",
      },
    ].forEach((dependency) => addPackageJsonDependency(tree, dependency));
  };
```

This works fine when the project is already created but my main schematic pretends to create a new project with my custom files and configuration. The main schematic looks like this:

```
import {
  apply,
  chain,
  empty,
  externalSchematic,
  mergeWith,
  Rule,
  schematic,
  SchematicContext,
  Tree,
} from "@angular-devkit/schematics";

import {
  Schema as NgNewOptions,
  Style,
} from "@schematics/angular/ng-new/schema";

export function newProject(options: NgNewOptions): Rule {
  return async (_tree: Tree, _context: SchematicContext) => {
    options.style = Style.Scss;

    const ngNewOriginal = externalSchematic(
      "@schematics/angular",
      "ng-new",
      options
    );
    const customStarter = schematic("angular-starter", options);

    return chain([mergeWith(apply(empty(), [ngNewOriginal, customStarter]))]);
  };
}
```

Inside the angular-starter i call my custom files. What i read is that problem with the addPackageJsonDependency cannot make its thing because the creation of the files its done after everything else so it doesnt find a package.json. I also tried to add my custom package but i think thats not the way because i want to be updated with anything that angular does in every new version

Comment: I have the same problem.
Did you finally acomplish it?